# Iterative function to hide/show multiple images with for and if statements

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, if-statement

I want to hide and show mulitple images, depending on the input code "places" inside the 'ShowPicture'-function. Please see my full example code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<style>
body {font-size: 30px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle}
#containertop {background-color: #808080; width: 100%; position:right}
#parent {display:flex;}
#containercircle {width: 30%;}
#containerimg {background-color: rgba(50,0,50,1);flex:1;}
header, footer {padding: 1em; color: rgba(50,0,50,1);background-color: #808080;clear: left;text-align: center}
#circle {width:100px;float:left;margin:5px; overflow:hidden; height:100px; -webkit-border-radius:50%; -moz-border-radius:50%; border-radius:50%; background-color:rgba(50,0,50,1); font-size:15px; line-height:100px}    #circle:hover{font-size:16.5px;margin:5px;transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out}
.crop {width:40px;height:40px;}
</style>
<script>function ShowPicture(tekst, places){
     for (var i = 0, i < places.length; i++) {
        var idCust ="pic" + places[i];
        var imag = document.getElementById(idCust);
     if(imag.style.display === 'block'){ 
         imag.style.display = 'none'; tekst.style.color = '';} 
     else { 
         imag.style.display = 'block'; tekst.style.color = 'red';}}}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header><h1><div id="containertop">header</div></h1></header>
<div id="parent">
<div id ="containercircle" float = "right">
<div id="circle" onclick="ShowPicture(this,1)">Test</div>
</div>
<div id ="containerimg" >
<img id="pic0" class ="crop" src="boor.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
<img id="pic1" class ="crop" src="boor.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
<img id="pic2" class ="crop" src="boor.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
<img id="pic3" class ="crop" src="boor.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
</div>
</div>
<footer><div id="containertop">footer</div></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

two examples of a "places" code is

> "123" and "24"

The function should read off the three numbers separately and hide or show the corresponding "idCust" from the css part. I have made id's in the css that is named "pic1", "pic2", etc.

For some reason, this is not working when I call the "ShowPicture" function after clicking on a div with the "onclick" statement. I got the feeling it has something to do with my for loop.. maybe there is a way to hide/show all together at once, but it should only show the images that correspond to the div I clicked on.

Comment: Post your HTML code, and try to make a sample demo.

Comment: Hope this helps! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an error in your loop the comma in `for (var i = 0, i < places.length; i++)`, should be replaced with a semicolon.

Another thing you were looping on a `string` and you passed `1` which is a `Number` so there won't be any loop, you need to pass it as a `string` in:

```
onclick="ShowPicture(this,'1')"
```

**Demo:**

```js
function ShowPicture(tekst, places) {
  for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
    var idCust = "pic" + places[i];
    var imag = document.getElementById(idCust);
    if (imag) {
      if (imag.style.display === 'block') {
        imag.style.display = 'none';
        tekst.style.color = '';
      } else {
        imag.style.display = 'block';
        tekst.style.color = 'red';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle
}

#containertop {
  background-color: #808080;
  width: 100%;
  position: right
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#containercircle {
  width: 30%;
}

#containerimg {
  background-color: rgba(50, 0, 50, 1);
  flex: 1;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: rgba(50, 0, 50, 1);
  background-color: #808080;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center
}

#circle {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(50, 0, 50, 1);
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 100px
}

#circle:hover {
  font-size: 16.5px;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out
}

.crop {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <div id="containertop">header</div>
  </h1>
</header>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="containercircle" float="right">
    <div id="circle" onclick="ShowPicture(this,'1')">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerimg">
    <img id="pic0" class="crop" src="boor.jpg" style="display:none;" />
    <img id="pic1" class="crop" src="boor.jpg" style="display:none;" />
    <img id="pic2" class="crop" src="boor.jpg" style="display:none;" />
    <img id="pic3" class="crop" src="boor.jpg" style="display:none;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tjavajive You are welcome, glad it helps, but just to mention that you can improve the code by testing over `imag`, if it's not `null` enter the `if` block and do the show/hide job, you can see it in my edit. :)

Comment: again, thank you for the updates. I think I have lot more to learn, but it is good to consider this additional if-statement. I am actually writing the script in python, then converting it to html, which makes it harder to spot the comma errors etc.